# IntelliJ Idea: test resources not detected

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using `build-helper-maven-plugin` to add test sources and resources:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-source</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/it/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-resource</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/it/java</directory>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The test resource directories `src/it/resources` and `src/it/java` are not being detected as a test resource by Idea:

[image]

I tried to re-import Maven project, restarting, invalidate caches, etc.

My Idea version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.8 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.5684.4, built on April 3, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b43 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.6
```

Thanks!

Comment: I want to avoid solutions where I have to change the project settings because everyone should get the project working from the pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it updating IDEA to 2020 version.